# Resharper and Phantom js failing to run

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs

I am attempting to run jasmine tests with resharper and phantomjs. I have downloaded and pointed resharper to the phantom js exe. Now I recieve this error:

[image]

If I run the testrunner without phantom it works fine. I don't want to open a browser every time i write tests though.

Comment: How did you download/"install" it? If you've done this through npm, then you probably need to point to the actual exe and not the batch file.

Comment: I downloaded the zip and point to the exe